# "Failed to run constructor: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PluginManager" in Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phone Gap to develop an app in Android. While deploying the app on emulator, I am getting this error logs

```
01-25 12:41:13.773: D/PhoneGapLog(491): Failed to run constructor: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PluginManager
01-25 12:41:13.773: D/PhoneGapLog(491): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.3.0.js: Line 210 : Failed to run constructor: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PluginManager
01-25 12:41:13.773: I/Web Console(491): Failed to run constructor: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PluginManager at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.3.0.js:210
```

Even though my application works, then also the errors comes.

My **.js** file is

```
function GpsDetactionPlugin() {
};

GpsDetactionPlugin.prototype.checkGPS = function(suc,fail) {

 return PhoneGap.exec(suc, fail, "GpsDetactionPlugin", "gpsDetect", [null]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("gpsDetaction", new GpsDetactionPlugin());
});
```

Why am i getting this unnecessary error log.How to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS code looks fine to me and I suspect the issue is somewhere else. I have a sample phonegap plugin at the following location which you can check to see that you have put all the configurations correct. Make sure you have put the plugin info in res/xml/plugin.xml

https://github.com/dhavaln/phonegap-examples/tree/master/phonegap-plugin-test